# How can I do to access to psql using bash?

Tags: postgresql, bash, psql

I am trying to do a bash file to use psql but I don't achieve ...

Here is my file :

```
sudo su -
su - postgres
psql
```

But when I launch my bash file I have to type my password for the root user but then I have close my root session to see the others command executed ...

How can I do that to execute the following command as root :

```
su - postgres
psql
```

Thank you very much !

Comment: Why not just use `psql` from your normal user account? Remember your database user is not the same as the system user, though if you do not specify `-U` to `psql` it will use the system user name as the database user.

Answer (score 0):

That could be combined to something like:

```
sudo -u postgres psql
```

However, this should only be done for initial set up and maintenance operations.  Create another database account which can accessed without sudo for everyday use.  (This might involve changing pg_hba.conf away from its original defaults).